# Getting error as "Cannot read property 'access_token' of undefined at test-script inside 'RequestName'" while running the API with newman

Tags: api, newman

I tried to run the API in the newman but it is displaying me the error, the same is working fine in Postman.

I have declared the access token in the environment variable and the error I'm getting while running it with newman is "Cannot read property 'access_token' of undefined at test-script inside 'RequestName'"

In the Login API in test I have written below code

```
var response_json= JSON.parse(responseBody);

var accesstoken= pm.environment.set('accesstoken',"" +response_json.Result.access_token);

console.log('Access Token is ' +accesstoken);

pm.test("Status code is 200", function () {
    pm.response.to.have.status(200);
});
```

to set the access token as variable for Logout (another API).
This is working fine is postman, but when running it through newman, above issue is coming.

Comment: Can you include the test scripts you have please.

Comment: This is the command I wrote to set the Access token in environment variable.
pm.environment.set('accesstoken',"" +access_token);

Comment: Can you update the original question with the details of the test script, don't reply with this in the comments. That particular command would cause an error on it's own, unless you're doing something else in the script.